# regex doesn't work in browser

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex is in the rubular page and its working perfectly: http://rubular.com/r/vtflEgDdkY

But in local host, I could not use it...
Here is my codes

```
var file = readTextFile("story.txt") // not empty
var result = file.match(/(::head.*?$^.*?$)^\s*$/m)

console.log(result) // writes null
```

**file** variable is not empty and readTextFile() function is working.

Here is the story.txt

```
::head
line 1
line 2
line 3

::content
content 1
content 2
content 3
```

Regex is not working... Where is the problem?

Comment: since you already know `readTextFile` is not the problem, just remove it from your question, and replace `file` with a sample string.

Comment: Then there wasn't a match, we need to see what the value of `file` is. There isn't enough information provided to know what is going wrong.

Comment: @Fabricator fixed, sorry about this I forgot.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I edited my question.

Comment: @ozer I mean just give use the exact value of `file` as a string that your function returns. Although that text doesn't match the regexp.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I tried that way but nothing changed... also this regex only works rubular. not other tester sites.

Comment: @ozer Where? I don't see an edit where you stated what the value of `file` directly is. The white space might be dealt with differently compared to the text file.

Comment: The reason why it's finding it is because in Ruby the `m` modifer allows the `.` to include the new line character. For other languages you want to include new line `(.|\n)` rather than just `.`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek In other languages you use the `s` option to allow `.` to match newline.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek how can I edit this regex according to your words?

Comment: @Barmar Yes in some other languages but not in JavaScript, that's not supported. I guess I was meaning in JS rather than other languages. Although `. --> (.|\n)` will work in any language that has regexp support and doesn't support the `s` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

If you're looking to capture both the head and content at the same time, you could use this expression

```regex
::head\n((?:(?!\n+::).)*)\n+::content\n((?:(?!\n+::).)*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/oX8vR6/1

**Sample text**

```
::head
line 1
line 2
line 3

::content
content 1
content 2
content 3
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture group 1 gets the values in the `head`
- Capture group 2 gets the values in the `content`

```
1.  [7-27]  `line 1
line 2
line 3`

2.  [39-69] `content 1
content 2
content 3 `
```

**Javascript Code Example:**

```Javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /::head[\r\n]((?:(?![\r\n]+::).)*)[\n\r]+::content[\r\n]((?:(?![\r\n]+::).)*)$/;
  var sourcestring = "  ---- your sample text goes here ----  ";
  var results = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
    results[i] = matches;
    for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
      alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
    }
    i++;
  }
</script>
```

Sample Output

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ::head
line 1
line 2
line 3

::content
content 1
content 2
content 3 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
line 1
line 2
line 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
content 1
content 2
content 3 
        )

)
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ::head                   '::head'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \n+                      '\n' (newline) (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ::                       '::'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n+                      '\n' (newline) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ::content                '::content'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        \n+                      '\n' (newline) (1 or more times
                                 (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        ::                       '::'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I updated the answer to include a brief javascript example.

Comment: thanks for all these. but there is a problem in your js code. it makes browser  stuck. there is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var s = "::head\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3\n\n::content\ncontent 1\ncontent 2\ncontent 3\n\n";

var r = s.match(/(::head[\s\S]+?)\n\n/);
console.log(r);
```

**Output:**

```
["::head\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3\n\n", "::head\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3"]
```